# AngularJS and RequireJS Unique Case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, bower

I have an experimental project using requirejs and angularjs. Below is my project hierarchy.

- bower_components

  - angular

    - angular.js
    - angular.min.js
    - ...
- app

  - main.js
- index.html

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Tes</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            {{message}}
            <!-- angular templating -->
            <!-- this is where content will be injected -->

        </div>
        <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="apps/main"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'bower_components',
    paths: {
        'apps': '../apps',
        'angular-min': 'angular/angular.min'
    }
});

require(['angular-min'], function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
    });
});
```

When I opened index.html in my browser, it worked. But, when I use F12 Developer Tool, the application loads two angularjs file, angular.js and angular.min.js.
But in the `<head>` section, the requirejs only includes the minified version of angularjs only. Why could this be happened?

Comment: Why loading Angular twice ? angular.js and angular.min.js are supposed to do the same things, isnt it  ?

Comment: yes, but it loaded both angular.js and angular.min.js. I just need to load angular.min.js only.

Comment: But, when i renamed angular.min.js to angular.js, it just loaded single angular.js file. Weird...

Comment: Maybe a cache problem ? To avoid caching of your files client side you can add `urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()`in require.config (and remove it when it's time to put the code in production)

Comment: I just added in require.config. In the F12 DevTool, i saw both angular.js and angular.min.js?bust=[TIMESTAMP]. I also tried to remove all cookies and cached files from the browser, but it still happened.

Comment: I think this is a bug on requirejs. Not only angularjs, jquery also same. It loads both jquery.js and jquery.min.js. I'm using bower for dependency manager.....